# preg_replace not work on server as localhost?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am replacing words matching with '##' in `$newstring`, This replaces all words on localhost
successfully but ignores many words when I run this code on a live server.

Any suggestions what may be causing this or how I could go about fixing it?

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
      {
       $commanword = trim(strtolower($result[$i]['Words']));
       $newstring = preg_replace("/\b".$commanword."\b/i", '##', $newstring);
      }
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. What do `$commanword` and `$newstring` contain when you run it on the server?

Comment: $commanword have words like 'a','an','the','was'        and $newstring have string  i want remove common words from string

Comment: both variables having same values on server And local when i am tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
  {
   $commanword = trim(strtolower($result[$i]['Words']));
   $pre = "/\\b" . $commanword . "\\b/i";
   $newstring = preg_replace($pre, '##', $newstring);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
  $commanword = trim(strtolower($r['Words']));
  $newstring = preg_replace("/\\b$commanword\\b/i", '##', $newstring);
}
```

There's some stylistic changes in there.  (I'd like a better name for $r, but I have no idea what it represents).  The substantive change though is that you're missing a backslash on the '\b' patterns.  The interpretation of the double-quoted string turns "\b" into "b" before it goes to the regular expression function.

Comment: $newstring = preg_replace("/\\b$commanword\\b/i", '##', $newstring); is again not work on server but work on local

Comment: it may be problem by preg_replace

Answer (score 1):

hey friends i have fixed it.
 it's problem of PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Supportdisabled on our server now it work on server when i make it enable Thanks both of you mc0e and Joran Den Houting

Comment: Which is the configuration file to enable this?